# How to convert a string variable to date format in SAS?

Tags: string, date, sas, format

The string variable is called start_date and is in the form of "SEP22", "JAN23", "MAY22" etc.

I want to convert this to a date variable in the form of "01SEP2022", "01JAN2023", "01MAY2022". How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use the [`input`](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.2/lefunctionsref/p19en16vskd2vhn1vwmxpxnglxxs.htm) function with the right informat to convert it to a SAS datetime.
- Apply the desired format

```
data want;
string = 'SEP22';
date = input(string, monyy.);

format date date9.;
run;
```

```
string     date
SEP22   01SEP2022
```

Comment: @willd9 Always be aware that SAS has formats and informats for interacting with raw SAS date values (days from epoch) and raw SAS datetime values (seconds from epoch). Formats take a raw value and render it to a certain string representation.  Informats take a string and parses it into a raw value.